# Strange, inconsistent behavior in checking whether a python list contains a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

So there's no issue if I do:

```
A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
B = [1,2,3]
B in A #=> True
```

But if I do:

```
A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
A = [np.array(x) for x in A]

A[0] in A #=> True

z = np.array([1,2,3])
z in A #=> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I find this very confusing. z and A[0] are both (3,) numpy arrays of the same dtype, and are equal everywhere.

Is there a reason for this kind of behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: Uh, I did google the error and I understand your point in general. But then why does A[0] in A work?

Comment: Ah, I see, re-opened and answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is subtle.  `in` will ultimately use `==` to compare the elements, that will result in a boolean array (with all Trues). However, `numpy` explicitly prevents arrays from being used in a boolean context... as explained in the error message. So this is one way that `numpy.ndarray` objets don't play well with vanilla python data structures.

However (and this is an implementation detail) `list.__contains__` which will be called by `in` will use `is` *before* `==` to test membership. Thus it will return `True` without ever trying to use the array in a boolean context, since

```
A[0] is A[0]
```

Although, note, I actually am not sure if it should be considered an *implementation detail*, because it's right there in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details):

> For container types such as `list`, `tuple`, `set`, `frozenset`,
> `dict`, or `collections.deque`, the expression `x in y` is equivalent
> to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`.

Would be interesting to see if other implementations, e.g. pypy or Jython do this as well.

Fundamentally, Python assumes that `x is y` implies `x == y`, although, even some built-in types violate this, perhaps most notably, `float` objects, in particular, `float('nan')`. Consider:

```
>>> data = [float('nan'), 1., 2., 3.]
>>> data
[nan, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
>>> float('nan') in data
False
>>> data[0] in data
True
>>> data[0] == data[0]
False
>>> data[0] is data[0]
True
```

Comment: Cool, that's very interesting. Thanks for reading my question :P